# How to customize entry widget and save input with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am interested in how to customize the given entry widget by additionally opening up another entry widget (here phone number) and save the input depending on if another entry is added or not.
This is what I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
  
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
  
name_var=tk.StringVar()
surname_var=tk.StringVar()
 

def getInput():
    name=name_var.get()
    surname=surname_var.get()
     
    print("The name is : " + name)
    print("The Surname is : " + surname)
     
    name_var.set("")
    surname_var.set("")
     
def addEntry():
    phone_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Phone', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))
    phone_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
    phone_label.grid(row=3,column=0)
    phone_entry.grid(row=3,column=1)
    

name_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Name', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))
name_entry = tk.Entry(root,textvariable = name_var, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))

surname_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Surname', font = ('calibre',10,'bold'))
surname_entry=tk.Entry(root, textvariable = surname_var, font = ('calibre',10,'normal'), show = '*')
  
name_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
surname_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
surname_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

save_btn=tk.Button(root,text = 'Save', command = getInput)
save_btn.grid(row=5,column=0)  

add_btn=tk.Button(root,text = 'Add Info', command = addEntry)
add_btn.grid(row=5,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I define another function for saving the additional phone input and save it using one 'save' button?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an additional function to save the extra input, just to modify `getInput()`.

What you can do is define an extra `StringVar`, `phone_var`, for the phone number (it will be `''` by default) and connect it to the extra entry you create in `addEntry()`. Then, in `getInput()` you can get the content of `phone_var` (which always exists even if the entry doesn't). If it is `''` then you don't save it.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

name_var = tk.StringVar()
surname_var = tk.StringVar()
phone_var = tk.StringVar()  # extra StringVar for the optional entry


def getInput():
    name = name_var.get()
    surname = surname_var.get()
    phone = phone_var.get()

    print("The name is : " + name)
    print("The Surname is : " + surname)
    if phone:  # save it only if not empty
        print("The Phone is : " + phone)

    name_var.set("")
    surname_var.set("")

def addEntry():
    phone_label = tk.Label(root, text='Phone', font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
    phone_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=phone_var, font=('calibre', 10, 'normal'))
    phone_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
    phone_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)


name_label = tk.Label(root, text='Name', font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
name_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=name_var, font=('calibre', 10, 'normal'))

surname_label = tk.Label(root, text='Surname', font=('calibre', 10, 'bold'))
surname_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=surname_var, font=('calibre', 10, 'normal'), show='*')

name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
surname_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
surname_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

save_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Save', command=getInput)
save_btn.grid(row=5, column=0)

add_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Add Info', command=addEntry)
add_btn.grid(row=5, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was just able to try it out ! you really made my day ! huge thanks :)